# How to pass custom data in headers in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

This is my provider code in which I am passing multiple data in headers

```
  postEventComment(body,headers){
      return this.http.post(this.api_comment_event, body,{ headers: {'Content-Type' :'multipart/form-data','userId':'1451'} })
      .do((res: Response) => console.log(res))
      // .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch(this.catchError)
      }
```

Here is my comment ts code

```
this.body2 = 'eventId' + '=' + id + '&comment=' + this.body.comment  
let headers = new Headers();
let body = this.body
this.api_list.postEventComment(this.body2,headers).subscribe(data =>  {
console.log(data);});
```

Below is my screenshot [image: error getting in console]

[image: Not getting exact header which I am passing in my code]

Comment: What is the type of this.http? Please provide a minimal reproduction of your issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be using something like this.

**code**

```
this.body2 = 'eventId' + '=' + id + '&comment=' + this.body.comment  
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('userId', 123);
let opts = new RequestOptions();
opts.headers = headers;
this.api_list.postEventComment(this.body2 , opts).subscribe(data =>  {
console.log(data);});
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'headers' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, according to your API, you are using userId at the wrong place. Instead of that, you should pass auth token. The solution to this mostly depends on API you are hitting.

Btw, You can use header with something like this:

```
const headers: Headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'userId': '123'
});
```

And pass it to you post request like this:

```
this.http.post(this.api_comment_event, body,{ headers: headers })
```

Don't forget to import Headers:

```
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

If possible please share API details to get more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed answer to the question:

> Pass data into the HTTP header from the Angular side (preferred version >= angular 4)

There is more than one way we can pass data into the headers.
The syntax is different but all means the same.

```
// Option 1 
 const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'ID': emp.UserID,
   })
 };


// Option 2

let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('ID', '001');

let options = {headers:httpHeaders};


// Option 1 Call the Web API Url.
   return this.http.post(this.url + 'testMethod', body,httpOptions)

// Option 2 Call the Web API Url.
   return this.http.post(this.url + 'testMethod', body,options)
```

In the call you can find the field passed as a header as shown in the image below (In the browser go to network Tab):

[image]